# Why does pie chart increase size after setTitle method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The event redraw calls the setTitle method where I update data with the method:

```
donutChart.series[0].setData(donutSeries);
```

The chart increases in size. I don't need such behaviour, but I need to change title dynamically.

```js
var chart;
$(function() {
  $('#ebtDonutChart1').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var total = 0;
          chart = this;
          var items = chart.series[0].data;
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total += items[i].y;
          }

          chart.setTitle({
            text: "<b>" + total.toString() + "</b>" + "<br/>" + " M €",
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 15,
            style: {
              color: '#666666',
              fontSize: '35px'
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        innerSize: 100,
        depth: 45
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Delivered amount',
      data: [
        ['Bananas', 8],
        ['Kiwi', 3],
        ['Mixed nuts', 1],
        ['Oranges', 6],
        ['Apples', 8],
        ['Pears', 4],
        ['Clementines', 4],
        ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
        ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
      ],
      states: {
        hover: {
          halo: {
            size: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  });
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    chart.series[0].setData([
      ['Bananas', 8],
      ['Kiwi', 3],
      ['Mixed nuts', 1],
      ['Oranges', 6],
      ['Apples', 8],
      ['Pears', 4],
      ['Clementines', 4],
      ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
      ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
    ]);
    var total = 0;
    var items = chart.series[0].data;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      total += items[i].y;
    }

    chart.setTitle({
      text: "2",
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      y: 15,
      style: {
        color: '#666666',
        fontSize: '35px'
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="ebtDonutChart1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle reproducing this issue?

Comment: Actually I can sort of reproduce it with a modified fiddle. What happens in this fiddle is that the point select "halo" is shifted up a bit. Move your mouse on the slices and you will notice. http://jsfiddle.net/g2j2rhm9/2/

Comment: I was set up a jsFiddle reproducing  https://jsfiddle.net/MasterMedia/t10huzLa/12/ Also I turn of a "halo" effect to fixed this bug.